# Is it possible to infer single probability from various combination outputs?

Tags: probability

Suppose that you have a combination of four cues (1234). Each single cue correctly predicts a given event (e.g., it will rain) with a given probability, depending on either it is present or absent.

Suppose now that the only thing you know is the overall probability that it will rain given a specific combination of cues. One example of combination could be '0110', 1 and 4 are absents; 2 and 3 are presents. You have this information for several combinations (labbeled A,B,...,M,N), as in the table below (sorry for the python dict formatting).

> combinations = {
>       'A':{'1':0, '2':0, '3':0, '4':1, 'frequency':0.14, 'rain':0.143},
>       'B':{'1':0, '2':0, '3':1, '4':0, 'frequency':0.08, 'rain':0.375},
>       'C':{'1':0, '2':0, '3':1, '4':1, 'frequency':0.09, 'rain':0.111},
>       'D':{'1':0, '2':1, '3':0, '4':0, 'frequency':0.08, 'rain':0.625},
>       'E':{'1':0, '2':1, '3':0, '4':1, 'frequency':0.06, 'rain':0.167},
>       'F':{'1':0, '2':1, '3':1, '4':0, 'frequency':0.06, 'rain':0.500},
>       'G':{'1':0, '2':1, '3':1, '4':1, 'frequency':0.04, 'rain':0.250},
>       'H':{'1':1, '2':0, '3':0, '4':0, 'frequency':0.14, 'rain':0.857},
>       'I':{'1':1, '2':0, '3':0, '4':1, 'frequency':0.06, 'rain':0.500},
>       'J':{'1':1, '2':0, '3':1, '4':0, 'frequency':0.06, 'rain':0.833},
>       'K':{'1':1, '2':0, '3':1, '4':1, 'frequency':0.03, 'rain':0.333},
>       'L':{'1':1, '2':1, '3':0, '4':0, 'frequency':0.09, 'rain':0.889},
>       'M':{'1':1, '2':1, '3':0, '4':1, 'frequency':0.03, 'rain':0.667},
>       'N':{'1':1, '2':1, '3':1, '4':0, 'frequency':0.04, 'rain':0.750}
>   }

So, for instance, the combination A (0001, i.e. only the fourth cue is present) occurs 14% of the time, and each time, predicts rain with a probability of 14,3%.

Is it possible, from this table, to infer the elementary probabilities of each single cue. For example, is it possible to know what is the specific probability relationship between the first cue and the event "it will rain". In other word, what's the probability of having rain if I have the '1' cue present, whatever the other cue states are (present/absent).

NB : (1111) and (0000) events are not possible in my case. They just cannot happen.

Thanks for your help,
And please, let me know if the problem lacks of information or is under-specified.

Benoît

Comment: A,B,D,H have it if they are alone but it doesn't seem to pan out to the others for me.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the specific probability relationship".  You need a model connecting the cues to the event.  A priori it could be the case that each of the $16$ possible observed events has an independently set rain probability.  If you think the relation is something other than that, you need to specify it externally.

Comment: Note:  maybe all you mean is "given that I know that cue $n$ is present, with no information on the others, what is the probability that it is raining?"  That one you can almost answer.  You need the other two scenarios (all cues present, no cues present).  If you have that then you just sum over the $8$ scenarios, weighted by their frequency, in which that cue is active.  I didn't add the frequencies...I'm assuming all $16$ scenarios are possible.

Comment: @lulu the frequencies all add up to 1

Comment: @lulu Yes, this is what I meant, except I do not have any information for (1111) or (0000) combinations, i.e., they are not possible events. Only events in the table might happen.

Comment: Ah, well if the frequencies add to $1$ then you don't need the missing two.  All you have to do is to weight by the frequencies.  Do you understand what I mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As remarked in the comments, the given frequencies add to $1$ so the two missing scenarios (all present, all absent) are not possible.

For each of the four cues we seek to compute the following:  Given that the specified cue is present (but with no information on the other three cues), what is the probability that it is raining?  Denote this by $P(i)$ for $i\in \{1,2,3,4\}$.

To compute $P(i)$ we simply weight the $7$ possible scenarios in which cue $i$ is active.  For example, cue $1$ is active in scenarios $H-N$.  It follows that $$P(1)=\frac {F(H)\times P(H)+F(I)\times P(I)+ \cdots +F(N)\times P(N)}{F(H)+\cdots +F(N)}$$

Where, for a scenario $S$, $F(S)$ denotes the frequency and $P(S)$ denotes the probability of rain.

With the given data we have $$P(1)=\frac {.14\times .857+\cdots+ .04\times .75}{.14+\cdots +.04}\approx .7555$$

Note:  I did the computation rather hastily, so I advise checking it.

Comment: Many thanks, this method did the job ! Problem solved.